# How to store values in when using Do?

Tags: procedural-programming

I am trying to plot a DensityPlot of a following integral, but I don't know how to store values generated using Do in a usable format. Following is the code that I have. Please suggest me a solution. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
    EQ1 = y1/((x1 - x)^2 + y1^2);

    Do[NIntegrate[EQ1, {x, 10^-10, 10}], {x1, 10^-10, 0.5, 5}, {y1, 10^-10, 0.5, 5}];
```

Comment: Reap[Do[Sow[NIntegrate[EQ1, {x, 10^-10, 10}]], {x1, 10^-10, 0.5, 
    5}, {y1, 10^-10, 0.5, 5}]][[2, 1]] or just Table[NIntegrate[EQ1, {x, 10^-10, 10}], {x1, 10^-10, 0.5, 5}, {y1, 10^-10, 0.5, 5}][[1]] if you can live without using the word "Do"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some numerical issues that need to be addressed when evaluating the integrand near zero. Other than that, substituting `Table` for `Do` is all that is necessary. Depending on how much you are willing to trade accuracy for speed, you can use

```
values = 
  With[{d = .01}, 
    Table[NIntegrate[y1/((x1 - x)^2 + y1^2), {x, 0., 10.}], 
      {x1, d, .5 + d, .1}, {y1, d, .5 + d, .1}]]'
```

or the slower but more accurate

```
values = 
  With[{d = 1/1000},
    Table[
       NIntegrate[y1/((x1 - x)^2 + y1^2), {x, 0, 10},
         WorkingPrecision -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 20], 
       {x1, d, 1/2 + d, 1/10}, {y1, d, 1/2 + d, 1/10}]]
```

In both case `values` produces a density plot that looks like

```
ListDensityPlot[values, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful!